# Coffeescript - complete static method skipped

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, coffeescript

Okay, so I'm very new to coffeescript and having trouble figuring out what's going on here. I'm using instagram-node-lib to build a hubot script. The `InstagramOAuth.prototype.ask_for_access_token` class complete method is just being skipped entirely.

```
robot.router.get '/hubot/feedbomb', (req, res) ->
  Instagram.oauth.ask_for_access_token(
    grant_type: 'authorization_code'
    code: accounts[account].details.theCode
    request: req
    response: res
    complete: (params, response) ->
      user_acces_token = params['access_token']
      response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'})
      res.end "Yup!"
    error: (errorMessage, errorObject, caller, response) ->
      console.log("Error on #{errorObject}: #{errorMessage}")
      res.end "McNope"
  )
```

I'm rather certain this is something I'm just not understanding properly?

**EDIT**

I'm adding in the ask_for_access_token method from instagram-node-lib just in case something stands out as obvious to somebody. I thought perhaps dot notation vs literal notation?

```
InstagramOAuth.prototype.ask_for_access_token = function(params) {
  var parsed_query, token_params, url;
  url = require('url');
  parsed_query = url.parse(params['request'].url, true).query;
  if (parsed_query.error != null) {
    return this.parent._error("" + parsed_query.error + ": " + parsed_query.error_reason + ": " + parsed_query.error_description, parsed_query, 'handshake');
  } else if (parsed_query.code != null) {
    token_params = {
      complete: params['complete'],
      response: params['response'],
      method: "POST",
      path: "/oauth/access_token",
      post_data: {
        client_id: this.parent._config.client_id,
        client_secret: this.parent._config.client_secret,
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        redirect_uri: params['redirect_uri'] === void 0 || params['redirect_uri'] === null ? this.parent._config.redirect_uri : params['redirect_uri'],
        code: parsed_query.code
      }
    };
    this.parent._request(token_params);
    if (params['redirect'] != null) {
      params['response'].redirect(params['redirect']);
      return params['response'].end();
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by skipped, exactly?  It never executes, or it doesn't execute before the code immediately following the call to `ask_for_access_token`?

Comment: @AaronDufour: It doesn't execute the code at all. But if you replace the method with something single-line, it will execute that just fine. So I tried creating a method called "completion" to be called on complete, but I can't pass params or response to that either.

Comment: Also, I tried using js2coffee and it tells me this is the correct way to do what I want. I'm stumped!